# Gtk# TreeView determine which item is selected

Tags: c#, treeview, gtk#

I am new to Gtk and I am using Gtk#. I am using a TreeView component and I wish to know when the user chooses a new entry.

I have tried using the TreeView.Selection.SelectFunction. However, this gets called before the selection is made, which is not what I want. I want to know what the user has just selected, not what was selected before. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks

This is what I currently have

```
catalogTreeView.Selection.SelectFunction = CategorySelected;


bool CategorySelected(Gtk.TreeSelection selection, Gtk.TreeModel model, Gtk.TreePath path, bool abool) {
    TreeIter iter;


    if (selection.GetSelected (out model, out iter)) {
        Console.WriteLine("abool = " + abool);
        Console.WriteLine("Path of selected row = {0}", model.GetPath (iter));
        Console.WriteLine(model.GetValue (iter, 0));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a handler for the ButtonPressEvent in which you can use the treeview.Selection.GetSelected() operation to retrieve the selected model and iter as you are already. NB. You need to add the GLib.ConnectBeforeAttribute attribute to this event handler and also add the event to the Events list for the treeview. E.g.

```
treeview.Events |= EventMask.ButtonPressMask;
treeview.ButtonPressEvent += YourOnButtonPressEvent;

...

[GLib.ConnectBeforeAttribute]
protected void YourOnButtonPressEvent (object o, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: So, I tried doing this, but the YourOnButtonPressEvent function gets called even earlier than the CategorySelected function I had. I need a function that gets called later, after the selection gets update.

Comment: Hi, maybe I misunderstood what you are wanting to achieve here. When you say called before the selection is made, what do you mean?

Comment: I'm making an app that is split into columns. The column 1 uses a treeview as a filter. Based upon user selection, I fill column 2.

Column 1 contains nodes called "playerItems", "courtProps", and "moves", each with subitems.

Click playerItems and column 2 is not filled since selection.GetSelected returns nothing. Click "courtProps" and column 2 gets filled based on "playerItems" because GetSelected returns courtProps. Click "moves", GetSelected returns "courtProps".

I need code that runs where GetSelected returns what the selection will be, not what is changing from.

Comment: Ah I think I'm with you. The CursorChanged event I believe fires afterwards. I have hooked into this event for selection changes in TreeViews and NodeLists. It doesn't need the ConnectBefore attribute.

Comment: The CursorChanged event was exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help.